# Reader rights by default in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions

My question is about database permissions and rights in Postgres. How can I create reader rights by default when objects are uploaded into PGadmin 4 schemata?

I created the following schema in Postgres called test_schema:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA test_schema
    AUTHORIZATION jessica_admin;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA test_schema TO group_members;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA test_schema
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO group_members


CREATE TABLE test_schema.test_table
(
)

WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE test_schema.test_table
    OWNER to jessica_admin;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test_schema.test_table TO group_members
```

Now the question is the following:
how can I include the following code

```sql
ALTER TABLE test_schema.test_table
    OWNER to jessica_admin;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test_schema.test_table TO group_members
```

into the default settings of PgAdmin4? I don't want to do this setting everytime when I add new shapefiles into the scheme, but I want that user (here called group_members) can read the shapefile in PostgreSQL and add this simply into the GIS Interface.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*objects are uploaded into PGAdmin*"?

Comment: The `alter default privileges` should do exactly what you want.  You just need to make sure you connect with a role (user) that is a member of the `group_members` role then the user will be able to select from any table in that schema.

Comment: I created a schemata in the Postgres (PGadmin environment). Objects are for instance shapefiles or tables. I added those objects to the schemata .

Comment: Yes, and the default privileges will allow (read) access to all tables in the schema `test_schema`. If you have other "objects" in that schema (views, sequences, ...) , the default privileges you defined do not cover access to those.

Comment: in my case the following code is essential so that other users (in group_members) can read the object, If I don't add the following code ```sql  ALTER TABLE test_schema.test_table
    OWNER to jessica_admin;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test_schema.test_table TO group_members``` then other user cannot read the object.

Comment: Then you are dropping the schema at some point. Changing the owner of a schema is not necessary every time you create a table. And if you really did change the default privileges you do not need to grant the select privilege either. To me this sounds as if you are dropping that schema each time you create a new table.

Comment: yes you are right! In my case I need the following setting always when I add a new object ```sql GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test_schema.test_table TO group_members```

Comment: Why do you drop the schema every time? You only need to create it once. And if you don't drop it, you don't have to grant the privileges again

Comment: actually I don't drop the schemata I just need to set the priviledges for the object everytime when I add a new object into the schemata. I need a solution that group members have reader rights automaticaly when I add a new object into the schemata

Comment: That can't be. If you really did change the default privileges you don't need to set them again after creating a new table.

Comment: right ! but with my code above It does not work! and I don't understand why!

Comment: The code you show works as expected--the final GRANT is not needed.  If your real code doesn't work, then you are not showing us the correct code.